# resolving entities for xhtml lacking doctype declaration with Java SAX

Tags: java, xml, sax, apache-tika

I am trying to parse the xhtml output from a Tika server. The xml inputstream (that I'm getting via an apache HttpClient) declares a namespace, but does not declare a dtd, the root looks like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
```

If I try to parse the input stream with SAX I run into errors if the xml stream contains entities

```
Exception in thread "main" org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 47; columnNumber: 37; The entity "rsquo" was referenced, but not declared.
```

I've tried to force the parser to use a local copy of the xhtml 1.1 dtd

```
    class XhtmlResolver implements EntityResolver {
        public InputSource resolveEntity(String publicId, String systemId) {
            InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream("src/main/java/com/w3c/xhtml/xhtml11.dtd");
            return new InputSource(in);
        }
    }

    SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser saxParser = factory.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader reader = saxParser.getXMLReader();
    reader.setEntityResolver(new XhtmlResolver());
    reader.parse(new InputSource(inputStream));
```

but it's still not resolving the entities. I'm still getting an SAXParseException on any xhtml stream that has an entity in it. Can anyone help me out here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have not posted the code that actually gives the error. But in case of Tika it happens because Tika is expecting well-formed html but isn't getting one.

One common scenario where this happens is when nesting ContentHandlers as below:

```
 ContentHandler handler = new BodyContentHandler(new ToXMLContentHandler());
```

Just remove the above wrapper and use:

```
ContentHandler handler = new ToXMLContentHandler();
```

And everything should be fine.

If this is occurring in other code snippet just remember that it is because the input HTML is not well-formed.
Check [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TIKA-1215) for details.